# qgis missing menu bar ver 1.8.0-lisboa on ubuntu linux

Tags: qgis, installation

QGIS emits the following warnings when starting, and fails to
display the main menu bar.

$ qgis --nocustomization

Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US]

Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]

Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already trackin
g action "Project Properties..." under id 125

Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::fillLayoutItem(DBusMenuLayoutItem*, QMenu
*, int, int, const QStringList&): No id for action

Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::fillLayoutItem(DBusMenuLayoutItem*, QMenu
*, int, int, const QStringList&): No id for action

The "//" in the path "/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US" looks suspect,
and there is no "qgis_en_US" among the 47 files in the i18n directory.

Help and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. How did you install your build? Some packages or from source? Did you previously have a 1.7 build? Has QGIS 1.8 ever worked on this machine for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, reinstalled python 2.7, upgraded qgis to 2.8.1, etc. My problem was caused by the configuration file.

```
sudo rm ~/.config/QGIS/QGIS2.conf
```

Executing the above in bash allowed QGIS to start up normally.